# Xcode editor copy command (command + c) doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.2

It happens sometime while writing code I copied text and tried to paste it using command + c and command + v but it paste nothing.

Comment: I face this issue many times not only in Xcode. I think this issue is from apple side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Edit` menu of the simulator and Uncheck `Automatically Sync Pasteboard`

[image]